# How does aws iot generate a certificate id?

Tags: aws-iot

I use Just-in-Time Registration of Device Certificates on AWS IoT. 
When the device certificate is registered, the lambda is started. Lambda uses a certificate id to create the name of the thing. For example: THING_66b9071648978494bec3cc2254362f4e9513bd886fb3f57ad9ee3ec9be0db931.

I need to know how aws iot generates a certificate id so that I can dynamically subscribe to the MQTT topics. For example topic: $aws/things/THING_66b9071648978494bec3cc2254362f4e9513bd886fb3f57ad9ee3ec9be0db931/shadow/update

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking but (from what I have seen) the certificate id is the SHA256 hash of the certificate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS IoT uses the SHA-256 hash of a device certificate in the binary [`DER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) format (not in the [`PEM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) textual format) to determine its `certificateId`.

A good way to retrieve the hash of a X.509 certificate using the SHA-256 hashing algorithm is to use the [`openssl`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) command-line tool.

```sh
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -in certificate.crt
```

Comment: You can further pipe that good result to get just the value, for example: ```openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -in pi-public.pem.key | tr -d : | awk -F= '{print $2}'```. I used that to compare IDs exported from the AWS CLI: ```aws iot list-certificates```

Comment: and further pipe it to replace uppercase by lower case `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -in pi-public.pem.key | tr -d : | awk -F= '{print $2}' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`